# How to bypass scanner check next element (if that makes sense)

Tags: java, networking, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a continuous thread where a server recieves/sends messages from a client however when I try to check for a next element it gets stuck:

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            ArrayList<Socket> connections = parent.getConnections();
            in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());

            while(true)
            {
                if(in.hasNextLine()) // Gets stuck here
                {
                    String message = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Client said " + message);
                }
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            socket.close();
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How do I make the loop not get stuck at the specified point

Comment: Define 'stuck'.  Do sockets allow for asynchronous communication?  Where's your inner `catch` clause, or what was the point?  Don't blanket-catch all exceptions - only trap the ones you can account for (except at the highest level of the application).  Don't use `while(true)` - check some condition, so the loop can be safely shut down; currently the user would need to kill the thread through some sort of thread manager (say, TaskManager), not a pleasant prospect.

Comment: By stuck I mean it does not complete the loop and waits for output from the stream. Only upon output from the client will the loop complete. I have fixed the try/catch statements and the while(true) loop is not the issue.

Comment: This suggests that the stream returned from `socket.getInputStream()` is 'blocking' - that is, it waits for input.  You likely need to do one of the following: 1) Wrap the stream initially received in one that will not block 2) Set the `TIMEOUT` option for the socket (And catch the resulting exception) 3) Use threading and queues so that the rest of your program can continue regardless of input socket state (This is probably the best option, and can be combined with the others somewhat).

Comment: How would I set the timeout? And regards to your third suggestion, that is what I'm already trying to do, I just posted a snippit of code from it. I have multiple files so I thought it would be tedious to post them all... Could you tell me what portion of my code you need?

Comment: If you're attempting to go with the third option, then the expectation is that it _will_ block, and resume when necessary.  About all that should be in that class, sitting in it's own thread, is the read, exception reporting/shutdown methods, and a way to push data to a queue (don't hardcode calls to `System.out`).  You'll want to read up on the [Socket Options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html) class for dealing with timeouts.

Comment: I'm not necessarily attempting the third option, I'm looking at which will be the most easiest to code. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to be able to deal with 'lines', I'd probably start with something like this:

```
public class SocketReader implements Runnable {

    private final InputStream stream;
    private final Queue<String> destination;
    private volatile boolean active = true;

    private SocketReader(InputStream stream, Queue<String> destination) {
        this.stream = stream;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public static SocketReader getReader(Socket toRead, Queue<String> destination) throws IOException {
        return new SocketReader(toRead.getInputStream(), destination);
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        active = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(active) {
            if (stream.hasNextLine() && active) {
                final String line = stream.nextLine;
                destination.add(line);
            }
        }
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log somewhere
        }
    }
}
```

Drop this into its own thread (or as part of a thread or executor pool, really), and you've made the rest of your application non-blocking with regards to this code.  **EXPECT** this to block while waiting for updates from `stream.hasNextLine()`.  You can even supply a `BlockingQueue` if you don't wish to actively poll a queue, but are handling updates in some other fashion.

You can then do something like this for output:

```
public class QueuedPrinter implements Runnable {

    private final Queue<String> input;
    private final PrintStream destination;
    private volatile boolean active;

    public QueuedPrinter(Queue<String> input, PrintStream destination) {
        this.input = input;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        active = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(active) {
            final String line = input.poll();
            if (line != null && active) {
                destination.println(line);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Please note that I haven't tested this, and you may have to adjust things slightly for other Checked exceptions.  You probably need to put in additional error-checking code (null-handling comes to mind).  Also, this isn't *completely* threadsafe, but is likely to be 'good enough' for most uses.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot actually. Sorry for the late reply, I've been preoccupied.